# Inkscape error with TexText

Tags: kubuntu, latex, inkscape

I have Kubuntu 16.04, Inkscape 0.92 and TexText 0.4.4.

TexText has worked without any problem for a long time, however, it suddenly stopped working and I am trying to track down the issue. I already reinstalled Inkscape and TexText, still no working.

Here is the error I am receiving (already look it up on google, no aid found):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textext.py", line 210, in cb_ok
    self.callback(self.text, self.preamble_file, self.scale_factor)
  File "textext.py", line 369, in <lambda>
    converter_cls, old_node))
  File "textext.py", line 387, in do_convert
    new_node = converter.convert(text, preamble_file, scale_factor)
  File "textext.py", line 751, in convert
    self.pdf_to_svg()
  File "textext.py", line 849, in pdf_to_svg
    + pstoeditOpts)
  File "textext.py", line 596, in exec_command
    % (' '.join(cmd), p.returncode, out + err))
RuntimeError: Command pstoedit -f plot-svg /tmp/tmpRoqG9M/tmp.pdf /tmp/tmpRoqG9M/tmp.svg -dt -ssp -psarg -r9600x9600 failed (code 1): pstoedit: version 3.70 / DLL interface 108 (built: Mar 13 2016 - release build - g++ 5.3.1 20160311 - 64-bit) : Copyright (C) 1993 - 2014 Wolfgang Glunz
Error: /invalidaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   false   --dict:30/32(L)--   typecheck   --nostringval--   -ueofill   ueofill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   ueofill   --nostringval--   -ufill   ufill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   ufill   --nostringval--   -shfill   shfill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   shfill   --nostringval--   -showpage   showpage   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   -awidthshow   awidthshow   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   awidthshow   --nostringval--   -rectstroke   rectstroke   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   rectstroke   --nostringval--   -stringwidth   stringwidth   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   stringwidth   --nostringval--   -charpath   charpath   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   charpath   --nostringval--   -ge   ge   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   ge   --nostringval--   -rectfill   rectfill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   rectfill   --nostringval--   -glyphshow   glyphshow   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   glyphshow   --nostringval--   -concat   concat   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   concat   --nostringval--   -image   image   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   image   --nostringval--   -currentcmykcolor   currentcmykcolor   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   currentcmykcolor   --nostringval--   -currentrgbcolor   currentrgbcolor   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   currentrgbcolor   --nostringval--   -string   string   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   string   --nostringval--   -lt   lt   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   lt   --nostringval--   -stroke   stroke   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   stroke   --nostringval--   -setgstate   setgstate   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   setgstate   --nostringval--   -eofill   eofill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   eofill   --nostringval--   -rectclip   rectclip   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   rectclip   --nostringval--   -eoclip   eoclip   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   eoclip   --nostringval--   -clip   clip   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   clip   --nostringval--   -ustroke   ustroke   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   ustroke   --nostringval--   -colorimage   colorimage   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   colorimage   --nostringval--   -restore   restore   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   restore   --nostringval--   -imagemask   imagemask   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   imagemask   --nostringval--   -save   save   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   save   --nostringval--   -fill   fill   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fill   --nostringval--   -grestore   grestore   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   grestore   --nostringval--   -definefont   definefont   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   definefont   --nostringval--   -gsave   gsave   false   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   gsave   --nostringval--   --dict:5/5(G)--   false   DefaultGray   --dict:5/5(G)--   ColorSpace   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1976   1   3   %oparray_pop   1975   1   3   %oparray_pop   1959   1   3   %oparray_pop   1852   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1976   229   3   %oparray_pop   1975   229   3   %oparray_pop   1959   229   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1202/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:302/450(L)--   --dict:302/450(L)--   --dict:132/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:283/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:26/32(G)--   --dict:0/6(G)--
Current allocation mode is global
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 87896
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
PostScript/PDF Interpreter finished. Return status 256 executed command : /usr/bin/gs -I/home/toquica/.fonts -q -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dNODISPLAY -dNOEPS -r9600x9600 "/tmp/psinovekHv"
The interpreter seems to have failed, cannot proceed !
```

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. My update log says there was a ghostscript update  a couple of days ago. If this is indeed the cause of the problem, you could try to revert back to the old ghostscript version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm this is due to the ghostscript update: reverting back to ghostscript 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 fixes the problem. So there is some regression in the updated version (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.4).

UPDATE: the bug has been reported at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1687614

UPDATE 2 (17 May 2017): the fix has just been released by Ubuntu, so it suffices to run the software updater to get rid of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm:
1) downgrade libgs9 to 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 with `sudo apt-get install libgs9=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2`
2) downgrade ghostscript to 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 with `sudo apt install ghostscript=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2`
3) reinstall pstoedit with `sudo apt-get install pstoedit`

After this, the system will detect the packages out of date, you maybe want to hold back the packages to prevent automatic updates

Comment: This worked for me!